# How can I append UIView to UITextView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I have big problem. I want add few UIView to text (UITextView, UILabel)
Each view contains ImageView with corner radius and text.
I want have result like this:

[sample from Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aw5ev.jpg)

I tried:

1. Add image with text by NSMutableAttributedString. In this case I can't add corner radius. And all images are from external serwers so it's problem with add to text.
2. I tried this library: [SubviewAttachingTextView](https://github.com/vlas-voloshin/SubviewAttachingTextView). In this case when I added multiple items all items were stacked on top of each other.
3. Finaly I used WKWebView and I inject HTML with CSS to WebView. But in this solution I have problem with fit content to frame size and is very slow. (for me is the worst solution)

Does anyone have an idea how to develop? Maybe there are some mechanisms in SwiftUI?

Comment: Check your spellings and grammatical errors before starting a new topic.  'I want add few Views'?  'I tryied'?

Comment: You can do this with image views and labels -- no need to put everything into a single UI object.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Custom class for a UIView and add subviews that you need inside that, and you can call that class when ever you want, in SwiftUI you can add this very easily by implementing a Label element inside the stack.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. I used NSMutableAttributedString and extensions on UIImage (download images and making circular avatars)

```
extension UIImage {
    
    convenience init?(withContentsOfUrl url: URL) throws {
        let imageData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        
        self.init(data: imageData)
    }
    
    public func withRoundedCorners(radius: CGFloat? = nil) -> UIImage? {
        let maxRadius = min(size.width, size.height) / 2
        let cornerRadius: CGFloat
        if let radius = radius, radius > 0 && radius <= maxRadius {
            cornerRadius = radius
        } else {
            cornerRadius = maxRadius
        }
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, scale)
        let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
        UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: cornerRadius).addClip()
        draw(in: rect)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}
```

and my sample code:

```
class NewNotificationsViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var testText: UITextView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.testText.delegate = self
        
        let url = "image-url";
        
        let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 22)
        let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
            .font: font,
            .foregroundColor: UIColor.orange,
            .link: "http://test.pl"
        ]
        
        let myString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Text at the beginning ", attributes: attributes)
        
        let imageAttachment = NSTextAttachment()
        do {
            imageAttachment.image  = try UIImage.init(withContentsOfUrl: URL(string: url)!)
        } catch {
            imageAttachment.image = UIImage(named: "avatar_k")
        }
        
        imageAttachment.image = imageAttachment.image?.withRoundedCorners()
        imageAttachment.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: -8, width: 32, height: 32)
        
        let imageString = NSAttributedString(attachment: imageAttachment)
        
        myString.append(imageString)
        myString.append(NSAttributedString(string: " THE END!!!", attributes: attributes))
        
        self.testText.attributedText = myString
    }
    
    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool {
        print("DEBUG", URL.absoluteString)
        return false
    }
}
```